# I can't redirect to an activity based on the request that comes from the web server

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-volley

I have a volley that POST a Mac address of the mobile to server and returns the respond in string "yes" weather the condition in backend satisfy, when i checking the variable stored the responds in if else the else condition is only working weather the condition is true or false. This are all in Splash screen.

this is a async task containing volley..MacAuth variable declared globally.

```
private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {


            /*  Use this method to load background
             * data that your app needs. */

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);

                final String mac = "{" + "\"address\"" + ":" + "\"" + MAC + "\"" + "}";
                String URL = "http://.....";
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject objRes = new JSONObject(response);
                            MacAuth = objRes.getString("statusCode");
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), objRes.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            //Log.e("TAG", "Error " + error.getMessage());
                            e.getStackTrace();
                           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mac, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        Log.i("macadresssented",mac);
                        Log.i("MAC", response);
                        Log.i("MacAuth",MacAuth);
                      //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), MacAuth, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e("TAG", "Error " + error.getMessage());
                        Log.v("VOLLEY", error.toString());
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    public String getBodyContentType() {
                        return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                    }

                    @Override
                    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                        try {
                            return mac == null ? null : mac.getBytes("utf-8");

                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                            Log.v("Unsupported Encoding ", mac);
                            return null;
                        }
                    }

                };

                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
                if(MacAuth.equals("yes")) {Log.i("checkifno", MacAuth);
                    intent = new Intent(Splash_Screen.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    

                } else {Log.i("checkifyes", MacAuth);
                    intent = new Intent(Splash_Screen.this, Error_Mac_Authentication.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }
                return params;

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (Object o){
            super.onPostExecute(o);
        }
    }
}
```

this is the logcat output

> I/macadresssented: {"address":"36:4E:07:GD:4B:90"}
>
> I/MAC: {"statusCode":"yes"}
>
> I/MacAuth: yes

Comment: move your `if-else` to `onPostExecute`

Comment: Still not working.. the else side is only work..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i moved if else to onResponse. Now it's working fine.

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject objRes = new JSONObject(response);
                        MacAuth = objRes.getString("statusCode");
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), objRes.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        if(MacAuth.equals("yes")) {
                            Log.i("checkMain", MacAuth);
                            intent = new Intent(Splash_Screen.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            Log.i("checkErr", MacAuth);
                            intent = new Intent(Splash_Screen.this, Error_Mac_Authentication.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        //Log.e("TAG", "Error " + error.getMessage());
                        e.getStackTrace();
                       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mac, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    Log.i("macadresssented",mac);
                    Log.i("MAC", response);
                    Log.i("MacAuth",MacAuth);
                  //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), MacAuth, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   try {
        JSONObject objRes = new JSONObject(response);
        MacAuth = objRes.getString("statusCode");
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), objRes.toString(), 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(MacAuth.equals("yes")) {Log.i("checkifno", MacAuth);
            intent = new Intent(Splash_Screen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
       } else {Log.i("checkifyes", MacAuth);
            intent = new Intent(Splash_Screen.this, Error_Mac_Authentication.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        //Log.e("TAG", "Error " + error.getMessage());
        e.getStackTrace();
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mac, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

You can try inside the try-catch statement.

Comment: that wouldn't work because that's in the `doInBackground` function

Comment: is it compulsory to use asynTask?

Comment: You can also do it without AsynTask.

Comment: i tried using without async..still there is problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
         StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UrlsAvision.URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    String MacAuth =null ;
                    Intent intent;
                    try {
                        JSONObject objRes = new JSONObject(response);
                        MacAuth = objRes.getString("statusCode");
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), objRes.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        if(MacAuth.equals("yes")) {Log.i("checkifno", MacAuth);
                            intent = new Intent(Splash_Screen.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();


                        } else {Log.i("checkifyes", MacAuth);
                            intent = new Intent(Splash_Screen.this, Error_Mac_Authentication.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        //Log.e("TAG", "Error " + error.getMessage());
                        e.getStackTrace();
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mac, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<>();
            params.put("yourParams", "");
            return params;
        }
    };

    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    AppWebService.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request);
```